# How to define filename yyyyMMdd<anycharacter>.zip for input dataset (Blob Storage)

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I work for the project: importing data from zip file in **Blob Storage** to SQL Data Warehouse. The files are in Blob Storage like below:

erp/lrc/Vendor_20171209125600.zip
erp/lrc/Vendor_20171209031200.zip
erp/lrc/Sale_20171209081200.zip
erp/lrc/Sale_20171209081200.zip

**erp**:root container, **lrc**: fixed folder

Vendor_yyyyMMddHHmmss.zip is imported to Vendor table.
Sale_yyyyMMddHHmmss.zip is imported to Sale table.

I create one pipeline for Vendor and one pipeline for Sale.

**My question is:** are there any way to define filename in input dataset like Vendor_{custom}*.zip with {custom}: yyyyMMddHHmm; *: any character to cover second part (ss) in filename? Like below example.

```
            "fileName": "Vendor_{custom}*.zip",
            "folderPath": "erp/lrc",
            "partitionedBy": [
                {
                    "name": "custom",
                    "value": {
                        "type": "DateTime",
                        "date": "SliceStart",
                        "format": "yyyyMMdd"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

And any way to delete the files which are already read by ADF?
If you need more information, feel free to ask me. I really need the solution for these stuffs. I read many articles but can not find the way out.

Answer (score 0):

As you also want to delete file from blob storage after it is read by ADF, I would highly recommend you make custom ADF pipeline. The reason for this is that ADF v1 does not have out-of-the-box solution for deleting files that are read. Because of this, you could also rename you file in the code (in any way you wish) with huge possibilities.

In order to achieve this, you need to implement `IDotNetActivity` interface in your C# code, more precisely

```
public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices, IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)
```

method. Here you can get any file, by filemask if you want. You can delete files, insert data into database, transform data, rename files etc...

Comment: For my first question: "are there any way to define filename in input dataset like Vendor_{custom}*.zip with {custom}: yyyyMMddHHmm; *: any character to cover second part (ss) in filename? => do you have any suggestion for me.
BTW, thanks for your solution delete file in blob storage, I will try it.